# Why are my chives turning brown on the tips of their leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, herbs

I grow chives in a pot. In the last few weeks, it grew dramatically. However, in the last days I noticed that the tips of the leaves turned brown.

[image]

What could it be? Some type of disease? Lack of water? Not enough drainage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't see the pot they're growing in in your photograph - if they have grown apace, as you describe, it may be that they're getting a bit short of root room and need a larger pot.

This type of thing happens with chives anyway, though - some leaves die back and any stalks which have borne flowers go quite stiff and eventually bleach and die back completely. Other than perhaps needing a larger container (turn it out of its pot and see how crowded it is) there doesn't seem to be anything much wrong with your chives, though I can't actually see the whole plant in your pic. You might check how dry or wet the compost in the pot is - they don't particularly like being wet all the time, so should be allowed to dry out a little between waterings, so that the surface feels just slightly dry to the touch, and don't leave the pot standing in an outer tray full of water, empty it after 30 minutes.

You may find they die back completely if temperatures get low enough - although this is an evergreen perennial plant (bulbs, actually), in places like the UK, they disappear below ground completely during winter, reappearing in Spring.

Comment: All of my onions do this to some extent, but I constantly harvest the greens for eating/seasoning, so all the stalks except the youngest have a brown tip because that's where I cut them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I have checked the roots and they still have plenty of space in the pot. However, what I noticed is that the soil was made solely out of compost. Perhaps, should I include some perlite for better water draining?

In addition, should pruning my chives make it healthier?

Comment: I would just leave it alone - I can see 12 healthy stems, at least two of which are producing new leaves up the sheath - of the remainder, 4 are going strawlike and 4 have brown tips (which might be from cutting anyway). Which means of 20 stems, there is a higher ratio of healthy growth - although I can't see the whole plant, so if what's out of shot is dreadful, that might change what I'm saying. Its doing fine, particularly for the time of year.

Comment: I had pruned (harvest) my chives back then and now new leaves grew fine. Thanks a lot for your time :)